# Solve a functional equation involving integrals: $\int_{0}^{x} f(t) \,\mathrm dt = \int_{0}^{ax} f(t) \,\mathrm dt + \int_{0}^{bx} f(t) \,\mathrm dt$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, functional-equations

> Let $a, b \in (0,1)$ with $a+b \le 1$.
>
> Find all continuous functions $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ having: $$
>  \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \,\mathrm dt = \int_{0}^{ax} f(t) \,\mathrm dt + \int_{0}^{bx} f(t) \,\mathrm dt
> \tag1 \label1 $$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

---

From \eqref{1}, by derivation we get the following functional equation:
$$f(x)=af(ax) +bf(bx) \tag2 \label2$$
By replacing $x$ with $ax$ in \eqref{2}:
$$f(ax)=af\left(a^2x\right) +bf(abx) \tag3 \label3$$
By replacing $x$ with $bx$ in \eqref{2}:
$$f(bx)=af(abx) +bf\left(b^2x\right) \tag4 \label4$$
Now, using \eqref{3} and \eqref{4} in \eqref{2}:
$$f(x)=a^2f\left(a^2x\right) +2abf(abx) + b^2f\left(b^2x\right) \tag5 \label5$$
Because $f$ continuous on a compact interval, cf. Weierstrass theorem $f$ is bounded, therefore:
$$|f(x)|=\Bigl|a^2f\left(a^2x\right) +2abf(abx) + b^2f\left(b^2x\right)\Bigr| \le M (a + b)^2 \tag6 \label6$$
The inequality \eqref{6} can be inductively extended to:
$$|f(x)| \le M (a + b)^n , \ n\ge 2, n\in \mathbb{N} \tag7 \label7$$
If $a+b < 1$, from \eqref{7} we get $f(x)=0 \ \forall x$, so $f$ is constant.

The only case I cannot cover is $a+b=1$. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Maybe try a taylor expansion of $f(x)$ and compare the coefficients.

Comment: @MrYouMath It's for a lower grade, can't use Taylor.

Comment: Just a remark not a solution: if $f$ is constant, say $f=c$ then you from your condition that $cx = c(a+b)x$ for each $x$, so $c= 0$ unless $a+b=1$. So $a+b<1$ is strictly different from $a+b=1$

Comment: Can we suppose $f$ continuous?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I also noticed that. Still, I have a strong feeling $a+b=1$ also leeds to $f$  constant, because of equation (2) and the fact that $f(x) = c, c \not =0$ is a solution.

Comment: @mrprottolo Yes, I forgot to add  f continuous (but I use it in my prove attempt)

Comment: @user261263 As a side note, your inequality (7) would be $|f(x)| \leq M (a+b)^{2n}$, right?

Comment: Also, taking $f$ as a constant (any constant), also does the trick when $a+b=1$. So, the remaining question would be if there are non-constant solutions in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regard the case $a+b=1$.

If we suppose that $f$ is continuous we can repeatedly apply your argument to get $(5)$ :
$$f(x)=a^2f(a^2x) +2abf(abx) + b^2f(b^2x) \tag5$$
to obtain for example
$$f(x)=a^3f(a^3x)+3a^2bf(a^2bx)+3ab^2f(ab^2x)+b^3f(b^3x)$$
noticing that $a^3+3a^2b+3b^2a+b^3=1$. If we keep going like this we'll obtain something like
$$f(x)=a_1f(x_1)+a_2f(x_2)+...+a_nf(x_n)$$
where $a_1+...+a_n=1$ and $x_1,..,x_n$ are approaching to $0$: let's say that at the step $N=n+1$ we have $0\le x_1,...,x_n\le\varepsilon_N$. Then we can write
$$m(\varepsilon_N)\le f(x)\le M(\varepsilon_N)$$
where $m(\varepsilon_N)$ is the minimum of $f$ in $[0,\varepsilon_N]$ and $M(\varepsilon_N)$ is the maximum. Taking the limit we obtain
$$f(x)=f(0).$$